# @Font-face onload method?

Tags: javascript, css, font-face, loading

I have a loading screen that (does an animation and) creates several `img` objects (JavaScript) that hook up a `onload` method to a counting method. Once the counting has reached the array of `img` length the loading finishes.

So is there a way to add to this with `@font-face` CSS custom fonts?

Comment: That's strange. What's the relation of font-style with img? @font-face is supposed to be applied to texts.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want to recieve the `onload` event for when your custom font loads (in the same way that you do for images)? That's not possible, but there is a hack using Adobe's zero-width font. You could apply that to some text, and measure when the width of the text changes (which would be when the font has loaded). http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2013/03/introducing-adobe-blank.html

Comment: @DavidPearce Could you post an answer? And some example code or instructions as to how it would work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the custom font in the css file like you normally would?  Maybe I'm missing something, but if you load the custom font using `@font-face` in your CSS you will be able to use the font at anytime in your page.

Comment: I wanted an on load event for the font. David Pearce has posted an interesting comment